# floating View displaying on hover in android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement some hints when a user is hovering a button or another `view`, I see that android have support for `onHoverListener` but I don't understand how it really works. However I did try to find a solution how to make a floating `editText` on a button hover but I didn't find any ideas.

I am thinking that hover in android is the same think with long click because you can't hover with finger without clicking the view.

Comment: Would it be the sams as onfocus or on longclick?

Comment: No I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

`OnHoverListener` is only implemented in 2 specific situations: **a)** when a Bluetooth or USB mouse is plugged into the device, or **b)** on Galaxy Note devices, when the *S-Pen* (stylus) is hovering over the object.

In specific setups/situations this can be a very neat feature, but unfortunately, most users will never even know it exists. For your situation, you may want to implement an `OnLongClickListener` for showing hints/tips as that is pretty standard in Android.

This example will show a TextView or ImageView hint for **5 seconds** when a long-click is initiated:

```
btn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        findViewById(R.id.hint).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                findViewById(R.id.hint).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }, 5000);
        return true;
    }
 });
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

I want to add up on Aaron's answer.

Some devices with sensitive screens - Samsung S5 comes to mind - don't even need an s-pen.
Just need to hold your finger 1/2 inch over the screen and it would trigger it.